# After Enable IDispatchMessageFormatter I see nullable parameters in service

Tags: wcf

after add my formatter to operation behavior :

```
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
    {
        ServerMessageFormatter Formatter = new ServerMessageFormatter();
       dispatchOperation.Formatter = Formatter;
    }
```

In Formatter I have empty Deserialize method cause I want to use default behavior

```
 public void DeserializeRequest(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message, object[] parameters)
    {}
```

but In Serialize

```
    public System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message SerializeReply(System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion messageVersion, object[] parameters, object result)
            {
//some code
             }
```

Problem is that after enable this class, parameters in service method always was show as  null, but in IDispatchMessageInspector class I see that parameters is send properly. I don't know why it's happening, I only add this message formatter code , it is possible that empty class for Deserialize causes this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we are implementing **IDispatchMessageFormatter** interface usually we are not thinking that method **DeserializeRequest** is something important as it is not returning any data. This is misleading as method needs to do something.

The easiest way to make parameters correctly passed is to use base **DispatchMessageFormatter**. Add it to the constructor.

```
public class ResponseJsonFormatter : IDispatchMessageFormatter
{
    IDispatchMessageFormatter basicDispatchMessageFormatter;
    OperationDescription Operation;
    public ResponseJsonFormatter(OperationDescription operation, IDispatchMessageFormatter inner)
    {
        this.Operation = operation;
        this.basicDispatchMessageFormatter = inner;
    }

    public void DeserializeRequest(Message message, object[] parameters)
    {
        basicDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(message, parameters);
    }

    public Message SerializeReply(MessageVersion messageVersion, object[] parameters, object result)
    {
        string json=Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        Message replyMessage = Message.CreateMessage(messageVersion, Operation.Messages[1].Action, new RawDataWriter(bytes));
        replyMessage.Properties.Add(WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name, new WebBodyFormatMessageProperty(WebContentFormat.Raw));
        return replyMessage;
    }
}
```

And initiate it in the behavior:

```
public class ClientJsonDateFormatterBehavior : IOperationBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription operationDescription, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        // throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, ClientOperation clientOperation)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
    {
        dispatchOperation.Formatter = new ResponseJsonFormatter(operationDescription, dispatchOperation.Formatter);
    }

    public void Validate(OperationDescription operationDescription)
    {
        // throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You can check the working example here in the [github](https://github.com/pwujczyk/ProductivityTools.Examples.WCFAspects) branch **DateTimeFormatterWithParams**

Answer (score 2):

There is no default behavior if you do not provide your own logic on `DeserializeRequest`. You need to either reference the existing formatter and delegate manually in your `ServerMessageFormater` or provide your own logic.